# Img not taking up full width of grid container even though set to 1fr

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a book store page and I want the two cards to take up half the page respectively (with 20px gap). I already set the parent, .book-cards, to 1fr 1fr and card-top, to width: 100% so that it will take up 100% of the grid area which is half of the page.

If you run the code, the cards are clearly not taking up half of the page.

```css
.book-section-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Recoleta', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.card-img {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-top {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #e3dcee;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width:fit-content;
    height: 100%;
}

.book-cards {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px
}

.book-title {
    text-align: center;
    width: 165px;
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-family: 'Widy-Thin';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-cards">
        <div class='card'>    
            <div class="card-top">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41rsAHrKw1L._AC_SY580_.jpg" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
            </div> 
            <div class="card-bottom">
                    <p class="book-title">Think Life Like A Monk</p>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class='card'>    
            <div class="card-top" style="background-color: #f0edf5">
                <img src="https://bci.kinokuniya.com/jsp/images/book-img/97805/97805525/9780552565974.JPG" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
            </div> 
            <div class="card-bottom">
                
                <p class="book-title">Wonder</p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have `width:fit-content;` on your `.card`. Remove that or set it to `width: 100%`. `fit-content` is relative to the largest element in your card. The "think like a monk" image is 331px wide. The other is 200px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `width: fit-content;` on `.card`.

```css
.book-section-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Recoleta', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.card-img {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-top {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #e3dcee;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.book-cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px
}

.book-title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 165px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-family: 'Widy-Thin';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-cards">
  <div class='card'>
    <div class="card-top">
      <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41rsAHrKw1L._AC_SY580_.jpg" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
    </div>
    <div class="card-bottom">
      <p class="book-title">Think Life Like A Monk</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class="card-top" style="background-color: #f0edf5">
      <img src="https://bci.kinokuniya.com/jsp/images/book-img/97805/97805525/9780552565974.JPG" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
    </div>
    <div class="card-bottom">
      <p class="book-title">Wonder</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card-top,
card,
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="book-cards">
    <div class='card'>
      <div class="card-top">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41rsAHrKw1L._AC_SY580_.jpg" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
      </div>
      <div class="card-bottom">
        <p class="book-title">Think Life Like A Monk</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='card'>
      <div class="card-top" style="background-color: #f0edf5">
        <img src="https://bci.kinokuniya.com/jsp/images/book-img/97805/97805525/9780552565974.JPG" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
      </div>
      <div class="card-bottom">

        <p class="book-title">Wonder</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).